# onClick is not working until I comment the while Loop inside my function

Tags: java, android

I have a function `goClicked` which is a `onClick` method of "Go" button, but when clicking the button, the function is not executed (I am able to say this because the toast is not showing).

But if I comment the while loop then click on the "Go" button, the function is executed (the toast is appearing).

```
public void goClicked(View view) {
    afterGoPressed();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    countDown();
    correctCount = 0;
    totalCount = 0;
    TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    String timetext = time.getText().toString();

    while (!timetext.equals("0")) {
        int sum = generateQuestion();
        pickOption = generateOptions(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: add full code please....also add afterGoPressed() function and others

Answer (score 2):

By putting a tight loop like that into your code the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) is "starved" and so the GUI never gets a chance to do anything.

A simple workaround would be add a bit of a sleep in the loop to let the EDT have a turn. But you really need to do a bit more research into how to do GUI programming.

As it stands the code looks like an infinite loop because the `timetext` variable used in the loop condition does not change inside the loop. `timetext` is presumably supposed to change in reaction to GUI events. If the GUI is starved and so doesn't get to run then `timetext` never changes.

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're dealing with an infinite loop.

If when you create the variable `timetext` the text contained in `time` is not 0, the variable `timetext` will never be 0, hence the condition to exit the loop is never met.

```
public void goClicked(View view) {
afterGoPressed();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
countDown();
correctCount = 0;
totalCount = 0;
TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
String timetext = time.getText().toString(); // <--- this will never change
    while (!timetext.equals("0")) {
        int sum = generateQuestion();
        pickOption = generateOptions(sum);
    }
}
```

Sorry, I know this doesn't offer much of a practical solution to your issue. Maybe if you let us know what you're trying to achieve with that loop we can help a little better.

But for all I know, if you block a thread inside of the `public void onClick(View view)` method of a `View.OnClickListener` instance (either by making it sleep with `Thread.sleep()` or by running an infinite loop), it will also freeze the rest of your app until the `onClick(View view)` method finishes. That's why you can't even see the Toast appear, although it's before the while loop. Because the main Thread was notified that there has been a click event, but the response from that event is never arriving.